# Binding iOS Library - conformsToProtocol failing when called after NSClassFromString

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I managed to bind successfully a native iOS library but when I run I have one problem with conformsToProtocol validation failing when trying to validate a protocol implementation in one class looked up by NSClassFromString.

obj-C Code:

```
Class cl = NSClassFromString("MyProtocolClass");
if (cl == Nil) {
    // Can't instantiate class
    result =  NO;
} else {
    // Check class is compatible with the protocol
    if (![cl conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]) { <------ FAILS HERE
    //class does not implement MyProtocol
        result =  NO; 
    }
}
```

Protocol Code:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)method1;
@end
```

My Binding code:

```
[Model, BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
public partial interface MyProtocol
{
    [Export("method1")]
    void Method1();
}
```

My class:

```
[Adopts("MyProtocol")] 
[Register ("MyProtocolClass")]
public class MyProtocolClass : MyProtocol
{
}
```

I think that NSClassFromString is not taking in consideration the protocols that I implement in C#.

Any Ideas how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: One workaround is to create an obj-C interface that implements the protocol and then Bind that interface in my library and use that interface instead, but I think Xamarin should handle this situations better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.iOS does currently not support exporting protocols defined in C# to Objective-C.

It's on the roadmap for a future version, but exactly when hasn't been determined yet.

Comment: Ok Rolf, tanks for your help. I'll stay with the workaround then. Hope the support comes soon because the solution would be much clean.